# How to fix datagridview table export to pdf c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

```
 PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);

        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText));

        }

        table.HeaderRows = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1[i, k].Value != null)
                {
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[i, k].Value.ToString()));

                }
            }
        }
```

how can i fix the problem that says

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index it - this error is in line that
>   if(dataGridView1[i, k].Value != null)

Comment: The error indicates you are trying to access a cell that does not exist. Since your code uses the number of COLUMNS for BOTH indexes `i` and `k`… then … if the grid has less rows than columns… you will get this error. I am guessing the `k` index should be for the number of rows… not columns?

Comment: Judging by your usage of `k`, I'm with JohnG. Your nested `for` condition should be `k < dataGridView1.Rows.Count`.